# Delimiting Char Array for Three Variables

Tags: c, sockets, client-side

I'm writing a program to parse a command-line argument into three different parts: *host name*, *file path*, and *file name*, however I am unsure of how to parse a single command-line argument and store the separate parts in three different variables.

I need each portion to create a socket on the client-side of my program. So far I've been able to parse the *host name* portion, but I get stuck after that.

Is there a way that, after parsing a portion of the string?

EDIT:
The string I'm trying to parse is something like `camelot.cba.csuohio.edu/~yourloginid/filename.txt`

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i, sk;
        char buf[256], temp[256];

        struct sockaddr_in remote;
        struct hostent *hp;

        if(argc != 2)
        {
                printf("Invalid number of arguments. Program terminating...");
                exit(1);
        }

        sk = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        remote.sin_family = AF_INET;

        strcpy(buf, argv[1]);

        for(i = 0; i < strlen(buf); i++)
        {
                if(buf[i] == '/')
                        break;
                temp[i] = buf[i];
        }

        hp = gethostbyname(temp);

        return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
I've implemented a `while` loop to achieve what I'm looking for, but I feel like it's sloppy. Is there a way I can improve it?

```
    while(tk != NULL)
    {
            if(c == 0)
                    strcpy(host, tk);
            else if(c == 1)
                    strcpy(path, tk);
            else
                    strcpy(fname, tk);
            c++;
            tk = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `strlen()` in  a loop like that, it computes the length on each iteration. Instead you can do this `for (i = 0 ; ((buf[i] != '\0') && (buf[i] != '/')) ; ++i)`, also the `break` not needed.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input?

Comment: I just added an edit for it.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using `++i` as opposed to `i++`?

Comment: `++i` means increment `i` and then evaluate.  `i++` means evaluate `i` and then increment it after the evaluation.  From the point of view of your `for` loop, it should not make a difference which one you choose to use.

Comment: Please review my answer below.

Comment: `++i` first is increment the value of `i` and after that the value of `i` is used, `i++` first is used the value of `i` and after that is `i` is incremented.  In the example above, there is no difference.

Comment: Sans my example, is there any sort of performance concerns when choosing between the two?

Comment: There is no difference except that `i++` requires a copy of the value of `i` to be stored, but `++i` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char st[] = "camelot.cba.csuohio.edu/~yourloginid/filename.txt";
char *host, *path, *fname;
char *ch[3];
for (int i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
    ch[i] = strtok(st, "/");
    (if ch[i] == NULL) break;
    printf("%s\n", ch[i]);
}
if (ch[0] != NULL) {
    host = ch[0];
}
if (ch[1] != NULL) {
    path = ch[1];
}
if (ch[2] != null) {
    path = ch[2];
}
```

**Output:**

```
camelot.cba.csuohio.edu
~yourloginid
filename.txt
```

Comment: Is there a way that, after each token, store the resulting string in a temporary variable, for later processing?

Comment: @Delfino use `strdup()` or similar, to copy the token returned by `strtok()`.

Comment: What if I wanted each to be stored in a different variable, like host name in `char host[]`, file path in `char path[]` and file name in `char fname[]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse that with `strtok`

A rough example for you case would be

```
const char s[2] = "/";
char *token;

/* get the first token */
token = strtok(argv[1], s);

/* walk through other tokens */
while( token != NULL ) 
{
   printf( " %s\n", token );

   token = strtok(NULL, s);
}
```

I didn't compile it but I hope you can use it as an example.

Here you have a complete example of how to use it
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm aware of `strtok`, but am wondering how I can use that to parse one string into three.

Comment: I added an example for your case. `token` has each value in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

When you know the delimiters, never forget you have simple pointer arithmetic available to you to split/parse any sting. `strtok` and `sscanf` are fine tools, but you can do the same thing manually. Here is a short example to add to your list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 128

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: insufficient input, usage: %s host,path,file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *line = strdup (argv[1]);  /* make a copy of argument string   */
    if (!line) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: strdup memory allocation/copy failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *p = line;                 /* pointer to the argument string   */
    char *sp = NULL;                /* pointer to use as start pointer  */
    char host[MAXS] = {0};          /* variables to hold tokens         */
    char path[MAXS] = {0};
    char file[MAXS] = {0};

    while (*p && *p != ',') p++;    /* find the first ','               */
    *p++ = 0;                       /* null-terminate, advance pointer  */
    strcpy (host, line);            /* read/copy host name              */

    sp = p;                         /* set start pointer at current pos */
    while (*p && *p != ',') p++;    /* find next ','                    */
    *p++ = 0;                       /* null-terminate, advance pointer  */
    strcpy (path, sp);              /* read/copy path                   */

    strcpy (file, p);               /* pointer on file, read/copy file  */

    printf ("\n host: %s\n path: %s\n file: %s\n\n", host, path, file);

    free (line);                    /* free memory allocate by strdup   */

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/split_host_path_file hostname,pathname,filename

 host: hostname
 path: pathname
 file: filename
```

**Updated** to prevent potential read beyond end of `line` with `p`.

Answer (score 1):

you can also parse with strtok_r as follows, since strtok is not thread safe.

```
const char *delim="/";
char *str, *savePtr;
char hosts[3][32];
int i;
for(i=0,str=strtok_r(argv[1], delim, &savePtr);(str!=NULL);str=strtok_r(NULL, delim, &savePtr), i++)
{
print("%s\n", str);
strcpy((char *)host[i], (const char *)str);
}
```

access host array elements, as it will contain the indexed values delimited by "/"